# Mapping XML values via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary

Have looked around at all the xslt mapping questions but cant seem to find help with the following specific case:

I have a xml file for example with the following values

```
<rate>
<code>AB</code>
<code>CD</code>
<code>EF</code>
</rate>
```

These codes appear throughout my xml which I am outputting via the xslt.
However whenever the xslt outputs these specific codes it needs to first map them to new values
For eg the mapping would be as follows:

```
Code AB -> YZ
Code CD -> WX
Code EF -> QR
```

Please can someone show me if and how its possible to perform this mapping throughout the xslt bearing in mind again that these rate codes can appear throughout the xml at various places and also that the xslt is doing a lot more than just this mapping.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well with push-style, template based processing you should be able to write templates to do the mapping e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="rate/code[. = 'AB']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>YZ</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rate/code[. = 'CD']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>WX</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rate/code[. = 'EF']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>QR</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then if you make sure you do `apply-templates` for any `rate` parent elements e.g. either a particular template as

```
<xsl:template match="rate[code]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or if you don't want to change anything then the identity transformation template suffices to do the job e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I would also consider to define the mapping in a file of its own and pull the values in from that file, at least with XSLT 2.0 you could do e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="mapping-url" select="'mapping.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="mapping-doc" select="document($mapping-url)"/>
```

where the file then defines e.g.

```
<mapping>
  <map in="AB" out="YZ"/>
  <map in="CD" out="WX"/>
  <map in="EF" out="QR"/>
</mapping>
```

and then you could use e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="mk" match="mapping/map" use="@in"/>


<xsl:template match="rate/code[key('mk', ., $mapping-doc)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('mk', ., $mapping-doc)/@out"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of writing a template for each value you need to map.

Comment: Great! I am going to give this a try! Thanks.

Comment: The above is not working but I think its because the xml structure is much more complex than in my example above. For Example:
the <rate><code> elements might occur at the root of the xml or nexted within other branches. What do I need to modify in the above to deal with this? 
Also I should add that the rate code is output in various template throughout the xslt in this way....
<xsl:value-of select="RATING/ABBREVIATION" />
I asume I need to incorporate the mapping into each of these instances? (Sorry I am new to xslt). Any help? anyone?
thanks

Comment: The code I suggested does not assume any particular position in the input tree for the `rate/code` elements. It assumes however that you use push style, template based processing. As for `<xsl:value-of select="RATING/ABBREVIATION" />`, how does that relate to the elements named `rate` and `code`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion - i was using rate/code in my example but the actual elements in my xml are rating/abbreviation. So then I am unclear why its not working. Does the code you provided me with need to be placed in any speciifc place in the xslt - ie shoud it be at the end to do the mapping at the end?

Comment: Instead of doing `<xsl:value-of select="RATING/ABBREVIATION"/>` in a template for the parent element of the `RATING` element you will need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="RATING/ABBREVIATION"/>` to make sure the templates I suggested are applied to output the values. That is how push style processing in XSLT works, you write templates doing the transformation work and ensure they are processed by doing `apply-templates` to keep up processing or to select the nodes you want to be processed.